# Dynamically adding and removing columns from asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with fixed number of columns in it, but i want to make the columns dynamic that is number of columns should vary based on the selected option`

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid_additional_test" CssClass="table table-condensed table-striped hover table-bordered static pull-left table-hover"
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="200px" OnRowDataBound="grid_additional_test_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test Code" DataField="Test_Code">
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="20%" />
<ItemStyle Width="15%" CssClass="colL fix_gv_clm" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="fix_gv_clm" />
</asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#F2F2F2" />
</asp:GridView>
```

`
Here's my code behind to bind the data:

```
grid_additional_test.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grid_additional_test.DataBind();
        grid_additional_test.Visible = true;
```

Please share your insights on it.

Comment: `for(int i =0; i < grid_additional_test.Columns; i++) grid_additional_test.Columns[i].Visible = (i < showNumColumns);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            BoundField bf = new BoundField();
            bf.DataField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName;
            bf.HeaderText = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName;
            grid_additional_test.Columns.Add(bf);
        }
grid_additional_test.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
grid_additional_test.DataBind();
```

Make sure you remove all the columns you added to GridView through markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can also uncheck "Auto-Generate fields" from column editor

check this
[image]